# fatal error: openssl/conf.h: No such file or directory | Home-brew OpenSSL on MacOS

Tags: terminal, homebrew, encryption, openssl

## Question

It seems like **gcc can't read the headers in the include folder** of OpeenSSL. Shouldn't the flags I added in the `~/.zprofile` help with finding that, though?
What am I missing?

---

### Original Task

Compile [this C program](https://wiki.openssl.org/images/0/08/Evp-gcm-encrypt.c). It will use OpenSSL to encrypt/decrypt using AES-256-GCB.

### Issue

When I try to run

```
gcc Evp-gcm-encrypt.c -o Evp-gcm-encrypt
```

I get

```
Evp-gcm-encrypt.c:1:10: fatal error: openssl/conf.h: No such file or directory
1 | #include <openssl/conf.h>
  |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

### What I tried

1. I **installed OpenSSL** through Home-brew.

   ```
   brew update
   brew install openssl@1.1
   ```
2. Added such lines both in my **~/.zprofile** and **~/.zshrc**

   ```
   export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"
   export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
   export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include"
   ```
3. Removed and re-installed the **Xcode command-line-tools**

   ```
   sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools                           
   xcode-select --install
   ```
4. Deactivated **Anaconda's OpenSSL** (it was being executed before the home-brew version)

   ```
   conda deactivate
   ```
5. **Linking** OpenSSL

   ```
   brew link --force openssl
   ```

   but I get

   ```
   Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/openssl
   ```
6. **Linking** OpenSSL@1.1

   ```
    brew link --force openssl@1.1
   ```

   but I get

   ```
    Warning: Refusing to link macOS provided/shadowed software: openssl@1.1
    If you need to have openssl@1.1 first in your PATH, run:
    echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

    For compilers to find openssl@1.1 you may need to set:
    export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
    export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include"

    For pkg-config to find openssl@1.1 you may need to set:
    export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig"
   ```

### System info

1. MacOS 12.5.1 (Monterey)
2. MacBook Air (Retina, 13-inch, 2018)
3. SIP disabled
4. Security set to none